# Codeigniter : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, loops, codeigniter

i am trying to iterate a result set using foreach loop. Below is my array  when i do **print_r** on result set

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [xml] =>                                            
            [qid] => 406
            [title] => Q by Sikander
            [description] => test question created by Sikander 
        ) 
)
```

Using following foreach loop

```
  foreach ($xmls_nodes as $value){
       echo $value->qid ;
       echo $value->xml ;
       echo $value->title ;
       echo $value->description ;
  }
```

now as a result it prints following

> 406 Q by Sikander  test question created by Sikander

but right after this it also prints following for each of the record and row

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property 'qid' of non-object

it give same line no in for error where i am printing these values and using die statement after this, please help me to get rid of this issue

Comment: You may use your foreach like this foreach ($xmls_nodes as $key =>  $value){ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert this object to array and then just use it as array:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($xmls_nodes), true);
```

Comment: this is what i am doing already $xmls_nodes =  json_decode(base64_decode($xml)); and then loop is preformed on xmls_nodes

Comment: Do you see the difference between your and mine code? json_decode(json_encode($xmls_nodes), TRUE) - you need to put true as 2nd arg - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php What is written there - When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; when false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When null, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects depending on whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags.

Comment: so no, you're not doing the same thing at all!!! You are converting to object not to array!

Comment: now it gives illegal offset error, same error but on array instead of object

Comment: are you keep trying to use $value->qid .... You have array, so you need $value['qid'] ...

Comment: just make a var_dump($value) and see what you have

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["xml"]=> string(1402) " " ["qid"]=> int(40736) ["title"]=> string(10) "Q by Bilal" ["description"]=> string(44) "test question created on 15-12-2020 at 10 14" } [1]=> string(3068)}

Comment: so you have array with 2 elements, 1st is array with 4 elements and 2nd is string .... You don't have an object class anymore(you post was about this) Please do some reading on how to work with arrays... Your $value[0] now is an array So just access is with $value[0]['qid']

Answer (score 1):

You have to do JSON-encode your object and then decode it back to an array
`[0] => stdClass Object`

```php
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($xmls_nodes), true);
```

then loop through it